# OpenVPN packet loss between network interface and tunnel interface

Tags: openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server that is setup to do tunnels over TCP connections with a bunch of other servers on various remote networks. It all works pretty reliably except for one of the remote servers. For that remote server, about once a day or so we can't connect over the VPN from the VPN server to a web server running on that server. After about 15 minutes, OpenVPN on the remote server will have this message in the log:

```
read TCPv4_CLIENT [NO-INFO]: Connection timed out (code=110)
```

And then the remote server will restart the OpenVPN connection and it works.

I have been able to run tcpdump on the remote server and the VPN server while this problem is happening and it looks like this on the remote server when I telnet to the web server on the remote server from the VPN server.

**tun0:**

```
17:23:35.965732 IP vpn-server > remote-server.http: Flags [S], seq 1905371748, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 234388092 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

**eth0:**

```
17:23:51.981758 IP vpn-server.51194 > remote-server.55840: Flags [P.], seq 1035:1138, ack 1, win 28288, options [nop,nop,TS val 234392096 ecr 529325214,nop,nop,sack 1 {1016:14557}], length 103
17:23:52.024782 IP remote-server.55840 > vpn-server.51194: Flags [.], ack 1138, win 1002, options [nop,nop,TS val 529365753 ecr 234392096], length 0
```

I don't have the traces from the remote server handy, but on the remote server I could see the incoming packets on eth0 and tun0 and the outgoing packets on eth0 and tun0. Also I could see OpenVPN keep-alive packets on the remote server when the problem is happening.

So to me this looks like the initial packet from telnet is getting sent to the remote server and a response packet comes back, but that response packet is never put on tun0.

Because this only happens with one of our remote servers, I'm assuming it's some problem with the network connection there, but I have no idea what. Maybe it's some lost packets or something, but when I've been at the remote server when this problem is happening, the network connection was working fine as far as I could tell. Also, I would really like it if it could just detect this problem faster and restart the openvpn connection when this happens.

I have "keepalive 5 30" set in the config files, but it seems like the OpenVPN keep-alive packets are actually going back and forth between the VPN server and the remote server when this problem happens.

client configuration:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote remote-server 51194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca-cert.pem
cert client-cert.pem
key client-key.pem
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
script-security 2
keepalive 5 30
```

server configuration:

```
ca ca-cert.pem
cert server-cert.pem
client-config-dir clients
comp-lzo
dev tun
dh dh1024.pem
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
group nogroup
key server-key.pem
max-clients 100
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 10
port 51194
proto tcp
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0"
server 10.242.0.0 255.255.0.0
status openvpn-status.log
topology subnet
user nobody
verb 4
```